# Accessing JQuery Auto complete with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the HTML of a JQuery autocomplete after a word is typed in.  To do this I decided to try selenium webdriver.

I had a read of the documentation and I think I got couple of issue.

1) I'ts not finding the search suggestions although I am pretty sure I am selecting it right

2) I don't know how to get the HTML to a string from an IWebElement.

Here is my code that doesn't work:

```
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://site.xxx/");

    IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("stext"));

    query.SendKeys("iphone");

    // Everything up to this point works, I put a wait in here just incase it takes a few seconds to load
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

    // This seems to come back empty but in developer tools for chrome I can see it
    IWebElement results = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("ac_results"));
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

On your result call add .text(); to end to get the text value of the element. 
Java syntax.

```
String val = driver.findElement(By.ClassName("ac_results")).text();
```

Or

```
WebElement we driver.findElement(By.ClassName("ac_results"));

String val = we.text();
```

Comment: Thank you for reply @bcar . For me Text is a property and not a method.  It seems to be for inner text and not full HTML.  Also I have no reference for "WebElement", am I missing something or did you mean "IWebElement"?

Comment: I gave you the java version. Iwebdriver is the interface.  You could try the javascriptexecutor and call executeScript("your javascript") and grab what you need that way.

Comment: Thanks.  I found out why it is coming back blank.  The source code for driver is not updating like it does in developer tools.  There is an empty div that the jquery populates with search results and after i input text and then check page source on driver it is still an empty div but chrome shows it as having the contents.  I am a bit confused now how to grab the html

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the javascriptexecutor, see below:  (C# version)

```
IWebDriver driver;
IJavaScriptExecutor jse = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
string body = (string)jse.ExecuteScript("return document.body");
```